# simple linear regression problem / estimating T value

Tags: linear-regression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysi3K.png)

which formula is used for this problem?

Comment: See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this diagram, you have for $j=0,1$

$\square$ The estimated coefficients $\widehat{\beta}_j$

$\square$ The estimated standard error of the coefficients $\widehat{\sigma}_j$

$\square$ The $t-$value $t_j$

$\square$ The $p-$value $p_j=\mathbb{P}[T > |t|]=2\mathbb{P}[T > t]$ (where I used that the $t-$Student distribution is symmetric. The degrees of freedom of this distribution is $\text{df}=n-k-1$, where $n$ is the number of observations and $k$ the number of covariates, so in this case $\text{df}=11$.

You can easily obtain the $t-$values as
$$t_j=\frac{\widehat{\beta}_j}{\widehat{\sigma}_j}$$
and calculate the $p-$values.

Comment: Thanx. Im understood.